Inquiry on Material Selection for Rapid Shape Transformation Under Electrical Control and High Mechanical Load
I am working on a project that involves controlling the shape transformation of a material under electrical tension. The material will need to transition between two distinct forms:
Form A: A flat plate measuring 300 mm x 300 mm.
Form B: A half-cylinder with a width of 300 mm and a radius of approximately 95.48 mm.
The transformation should be electrically controlled, and when in Form B (half-cylinder), the material must be able to withstand a mechanical load of 2500 N. Additionally, the transformation must be rapid, nearly instantaneous, both from the flat plate to the half-cylinder and back.
I am considering several materials and would greatly appreciate your advice on the following:
Nitinol (Shape Memory Alloy): Given its high strength and shape memory properties, it appears to be a good candidate. However, I am uncertain about the speed of transformation and the optimal thickness needed for Nitinol to withstand the 2500 N load while ensuring precise deformation between the two forms. Would Nitinol be suitable for this application, and if so, what thickness would you recommend?
Piezoelectric Materials: I am also exploring piezoelectric materials for their responsiveness to electrical stimulation. However, I am unsure if these materials can provide the required structural integrity and rapid transformation while holding up under 2500 N of mechanical stress. Could piezoelectric materials, like PZT, be used for this? What thickness would be needed to achieve the desired strength and flexibility?
IPMC (Ionic Polymer Metal Composites): IPMCs are flexible and respond quickly to electrical signals, but I am concerned about their mechanical resistance under heavy loads like 2500 N. Would increasing the thickness (e.g., 5 mm or more) allow IPMCs to meet the strength requirements for this application? If not, is there an alternative material that could combine the flexibility of IPMCs with higher load tolerance?
I have attached the 3D models of Forms A and B for reference. I would greatly appreciate any recommendations on material selection, optimal thickness, and whether there are better alternatives for this use case.
Thank you in advance for your insights and suggestions!
Best regards.

